# Element not interactable, even though element is in view of browser

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working on a script to download a textbook from a pdf site, however, when trying to enter the book into the search bar i get an error

> selenium.common.exceptions.ElementNotInteractableException: Message: The target element is not interactable and could not be clicked

I've tried to solve this by using `EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']"))` 
and using `time.sleep(4)`
nothing has worked, the search bar is in view as soon as the page loads, I tried using an additional time.sleep() for extra time to load, but it still says the element isn't interactable when it's right there

this is the code

```
driver.switch_to.new_window('tab')
driver.get('https://www.pdfdrive.com')
time.sleep(2)
driver.fullscreen_window()
# time.sleep(4)
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']"))
bkSrch = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='text']") 
bkSrch.send_keys(bookLnk)
time.sleep(2)
bkSrch.send_keys(Keys.SPACE + bookRthr)
```

`

I also tried clicking the element first and it still doesn't work

I have no other idea of what to do

Comment: If you bring up that page in a browser with no cookie history, it pops up an annoying pop-up that you need to dismiss.

Comment: I've tried locating it but I'm having no luck, do you have any idea how to do so?, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "(//input[@type='text'])[2]"))
bkSrch = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "(//input[@type='text'])[2]") 
bkSrch.send_keys(bookLnk)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,".fas.fa-times"))).click()
time.sleep(2)
bkSrch.send_keys(Keys.SPACE + bookRthr)
```

Just click the popup like so also your text search bar was using the wrong input tag.

Comment: THANK YOU, I don't know how you did it, but you did it, and for that I am grateful, there's more code i didn't insert because it's not relevant, but I've been working on this for 3 days and now I'l finish on time thank you my friend!

Comment: If you get stuck again just feel free to ask.

Comment: also could you explain what i did wrong when entering the original search bar tag? i assume it has something to do with indexing

Comment: The 1st element was uninteractable and not the valid search bar you wanted. If you go to the developer console and type out your xpath you get 4 elements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
driver.get('https://www.pdfdrive.com')
time.sleep(2)
form = driver.find_element(by=By.ID, value='form-container')
inp = elem.find_element(by=By.TAG_NAME, value="input")
search_query = "it is working!"
driver.execute_script(f"arguments[0].value='{search_query}';", inp)
```

You can run javascript code in these cases.

For the popup, you can try waiting for 5-10 seconds first (time.sleep(5)) and then search for the close button if exists (use try-except) and if it is there, simply find the close button and click it.

Comment: the popup takes a long time to appear for me so I'm unsure how long it is specifically is there a way i could wait for it without specifying  a wait time?, also could u explain what the last line of code does, i don't get it, thanks

Comment: using selenium, basically, you are coding in python but it gets translated to javascript. The last line uses javascript to interact with the web directly. In this case, I'm setting a value for a HTML tag.